# Div блоки уходят за экран

Tags: html, css

Есть 4 блока `div`  в одну строку, требуется сделать так, что бы когда появлялся новый блок слева, старый - уходил в право за экран, но не пропадал. 
Есть идеи?

Answer (score 1):

Идеи всегда есть: `overflow: hidden;` наше всё http://jsfiddle.net/nk2u6/

```css
.my__blocks {
    margin: 20px;
    width: 320px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px dashed #000;
}
.my__blocks .container {
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
    width: 9999px;
    height: 100px;
    font-size: 0;
    background: yellow;
}
.my__blocks li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    background: green;
}
.my__blocks li:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="my__blocks">
    <ul class="container">
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```